# Docusign compatibility issues

Tags: docusignapi

We are planning to use Docusign integration. As part of it we are in the process of completing sample application by integrating with our product.Our product is part of .Net framework 4.5 . Newton-soft  12.0 version reference  also part of our product.As part of sample application – We used Docusign 3.0 version reference along with Newton soft 8.0 and its working fine.But as per product , we are trying to add Docusign 3.0  along with Newton soft 12.0 but its showing compatibility issues.Please provide solution on the same.

Answer (score 1):

Ram, I'm assume you're talking about the DocuSign C# library/SDK, the nuget package. 
Version 3.0 is a very old version released back in 2018. We no longer support this version and it may not work.
We highly recommend you use our latest version which is 4.2.
You can find all the versions and history here - https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll/
Note that this version supports .NET Framework 4.5.2, not 4.5. It requires Newtonsoft version 11.0.2 or later.
All the information about dependencies and versions is also available here:
https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client
You can clone this repo and use the code to build it against 4.5 if that's your only choice.

Comment: Thanks for your response. we need Docusign dll which supports both .net framework 4.5 & Newtonsoft version 12.0. Please help us to find the same.

Comment: We can't support every combination. You can get the source and compile it with the versions you need here - https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client
Also, if you don't mind, please mark this as answered.